# Is there a way to measure the energy consumption of a program along with its max. temperature?

Tags: open-source, python, c, power-management

I have a program written in C or Python that uses multithreading for parallelisation.

I was wondering if there was an open-source GNU program that could help me print out the total (and at regular intervals) energy consumption (CPU and GPU) in Watts, along with the highest temperatures at the CPU and GPU while running this program in C/F.

Also, is there a way to print the max power of the system (CPU + GPU)?

I have tried using powerjoular (https://www.noureddine.org/research/joular/powerjoular), but it seems like this only works for one PID at a time, and it doesn't work on my Intel-based server. This program only measures energy consumption, not temperatures.